# In QC10, how can I find outdated tests?

Tags: quality-center

IN HP QC 10, I'm looking to find all tests that have not had their design steps altered in the last 6 months.   Having trouble finding the correct table and query to do this.....
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the DESSTEPS table, grouping by test ID. You can join this on the TEST table to get details on the test

```
SELECT DS_TEST_ID, max(ds_vts)
FROM DESSTEPS s inner join TEST t on s.DS_TEST_ID = t.TS_TEST_ID
group by DS_TEST_ID
having max(ds_vts) < DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())     --6 months ago
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I suggested an update as the OP was asking for tests that have not been edited in the last 6 months this should be < instead of >=.  +1 for the solution